# Downloading a byte array response using Blob?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, download, blob

Iam trying to download a file from api response that is in byte array format eg: �PNG\r\n\x1A\n..., the problem is its downloading but the pdf are empty its showing the correct pages.

```
 api().then(async (res) => {
        const myBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: fileType });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        const newTab = window.open(url, "_blank");
      });
```

I tried few of the solutions here but not seems to be working.

Comment: First of all, you should make sure that the data returned by your server is a complete file, and you can use the interface to directly open the PDF or PNG in the browser.

Comment: Yes it was issue with the server response